# Как из блока кода JS получить значение х за пределами блока?

Tags: javascript

```
     var BBB = document.getElementById("year-of-birth");
     var ZZZZ = document.getElementById("year-of-admission");


     ZZZZ.addEventListener("input", function () {
      z = Number(ZZZZ.value);
    console.log(z);
    });

    BBB.addEventListener("input", function () {
    var Fin = BBB.value;
    x = Number(Fin[0] + Fin[1] + Fin[2] + Fin[3]);
    console.log(x);
    });

   if (x<z) { console.log ("ошибка в дате поступления или возрасте")}
```

Comment: никак.. да это и не надо. цель какая?

Comment: в дальнейшем использовать для сравнения с другими переменными..

Comment: это действие будет происходит в каком-то событии. так?  вот в текущем сложите данные в переменную  выше текущего события (за пределами), а в другом берите данные.

Comment: попробуйте создать переменную x в глобальной области видимости

Comment: по идее хочу выполнить такое сравнение но х и z не выводятся из своих блоков..не могу сообразить как переписать просто

Comment: z и x  выносятся так же вне обработчиков событий.......создаётся функция, например `test` где происходит сравнение данных.....что в обработчике `ZZZZ.addEventListener` что в `BBB.addEventListener`  в конце вызывается эта самая функция `test`

Comment: Спасибо! это трудно для осознания, но теперь все получилось!)